# Cakephp 3: view.ctp sum two variables

Tags: sum, cakephp-3.0

I have a view that shows an associated array of Revenues. I have made a collection in the controller to isolate two variables that I need to add together and display as currency.

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $annualOperatingBudget = $this->AnnualOperatingBudgets->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Azinstitutions', 'BudgetExpenses', 'BudgetExpenses.ExpenseTitles', 'BudgetRevenues', 'BudgetRevenues.RevenueTitles']
        ]);
        $collection = new Collection($annualOperatingBudget->budget_revenues);
        $revenuesGroup1 = $collection->match(['revenue_title.revenue_group' => 1 ]);
        $revenuesGroup2 = $collection->match(['revenue_title.revenue_group' => 2 ]);
        $tuitionAndFees = $collection->match(['revenue_title.revenue_title' => 'Tuition and Fees']);
        $lessScholarshipAllowance = $collection->match(['revenue_title.revenue_title' => '- less Scholarship Allowance']);

        $this->set(compact('annualOperatingBudget', $annualOperatingBudget,'revenuesGroup1', 'revenuesGroup2', 'tuitionAndFees', 'lessScholarshipAllowance')); 
    }
```

I am able to see the variables with the debug kit:

```
annualOperatingBudget (array)
revenuesGroup1 (array)
revenuesGroup2 (array)
tuitionAndFees (array)
  4 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetRevenue)
     id 5
     annual_operating_budget_id 1
     revenue 1278
     revenue_title_id 5
     revenue_title (array)
lessScholarshipAllowance (array)
   5 (App\Model\Entity\BudgetRevenue)
     id 6
     annual_operating_budget_id 1
     revenue -257
     revenue_title_id 6
     revenue_title (array)
```

I would like to add the two 'revenue' s together

I tried:

```
<?= $this->Number->currency(
     ($tuitionAndFees->revenue) + ($lessScholarShipAllowance->revenue), 
    'USD', ['places' => 1]) 
?>
```

But I get several errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\Collection\Iterator\FilterIterator::$revenue [ROOT\plugins\Twit\src\Template\AnnualOperatingBudgets\view.ctp, line 49]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: lessScholarShipAllowance [ROOT\plugins\Twit\src\Template\AnnualOperatingBudgets\view.ctp, line 49]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [ROOT\plugins\Twit\src\Template\AnnualOperatingBudgets\view.ctp, line 49]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need in the view is the total of all tuition and fees, you can use

```
$tuitionAndFees = $collection
    ->match(['revenue_title.revenue_title' => 'Tuition and Fees'])
    ->sumOf('revenue');
```

This will return just the sum of the matched items. Do something similar for `$lessScholarShipAllowance`, and then in your view, simply

```
$this->Number->currency($tuitionAndFees + $lessScholarShipAllowance,
    'USD', ['places' => 1])
```

Comment: This actually eliminate the two foreach loops in the above solution. I always like to eliminate lines of code. Thanks Greg.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate the $tuitionAndFees and the $lessScholarShipAllowance before trying to get the revenue property. Something like this:

```
foreach($tuitionAndFees as $tuitionAndFee){
    echo $tuitionAndFee->revenue
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can just capture the single property in my controller and pass the revenue entity to a variable?

Comment: I followed what you wrote and was able to successfully get my answer. the only difference was I made a variable $tuitionAndFee = 0; then in my foreach I changed echo to $tuitionAndFee = $tuitionAndFee->revenue; I did the same thing with $lessScholarshipAllowance and then was able to add the two variables together.

Comment: to capture the single property in the controller, you'll have to get the entity. Try something like this:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-result